# Error with this NullInjector and have something like that: Uncaught (in promise): NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(n)[n -> n -> n]

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

**Here is the code.**

component.ts
Here I guess the reason is these imports or maybe something wrong with routing.

```
  import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';  
import { AlbumService } from 'src/app/_services/entity-services/album-service';
import { Album } from 'src/app/models/album';
import { ToastrService } from 'ngx-toastr';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';  
// import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { MatSnackBar, MatSnackBarHorizontalPosition, MatSnackBarVerticalPosition } from '@angular/material/snack-bar';  
import { MatDialog } from '@angular/material/dialog';  
import { MatTableDataSource, } from '@angular/material/table';  
import { MatPaginator } from '@angular/material/paginator';  
import { MatSort } from '@angular/material/sort';  
import { SelectionModel } from '@angular/cdk/collections';  

interface Artist {  
    Id: string;  
    Name: string;  
  }  
  interface Label {  
    Id: string;  
    Name: string;  
  }  

@Component({
  selector: 'app-album-crud',
  templateUrl: './album.component.html',
  styles: []
})

export class AlbumComponent implements OnInit {

    dataSaved = false;  
    albumForm: any;  
    allAlbums: Observable<Album[]>;  
    dataSource: MatTableDataSource<Album>;  
    selection = new SelectionModel<Album>(true, []);  
    albumIdUpdate = null;  
    massage = null;  
    allArtist: Observable<Artist[]>;  
    allLabel: Observable<Label[]>;  
    ArtistId = null;  
    LabelId = null; 
    SelectedDate = null;  
    isMale = true;  
    isFeMale = false;  
    horizontalPosition: MatSnackBarHorizontalPosition = 'center';  
    verticalPosition: MatSnackBarVerticalPosition = 'bottom';  
    displayedColumns: string[] = ['select', 'Title', 'Year', 'Artist', 'Label', 'Edit', 'Delete'];  
    @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;  
    @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort; 



  constructor(private formbulider: FormBuilder, public service: AlbumService,
    private toastr: ToastrService,  private _snackBar: MatSnackBar, public dialog: MatDialog) {
        this.service.getAllAlbum().subscribe(data => {  
        this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(data);  
        this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;  
        this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;  
      });
    }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.albumForm = this.formbulider.group({  
        Title: ['', [Validators.required]],  
        Year: ['', [Validators.required]],  
        Artist: ['', [Validators.required]],  
        Label: ['', [Validators.required]]
      });  
      this.FillArtistDDL();  
      this.FillLabelDDL();
      this.loadAllAlbums();  
      this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;  
      this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;  
  }

  isAllSelected() {  
    const numSelected = this.selection.selected.length;  
    const numRows = !!this.dataSource && this.dataSource.data.length;  
    return numSelected === numRows;  
  }  

  masterToggle() {  
    this.isAllSelected() ? this.selection.clear() : this.dataSource.data.forEach(r => this.selection.select(r));  
  } 

  checkboxLabel(row: Album): string {  
    if (!row) {  
      return `${this.isAllSelected() ? 'select' : 'deselect'} all`;  
    }  
    return `${this.selection.isSelected(row) ? 'deselect' : 'select'} row ${row.Id + 1}`;  
  }  

  applyFilter(filterValue: string) {  
    this.dataSource.filter = filterValue.trim().toLowerCase();  
   
    if (this.dataSource.paginator) {  
      this.dataSource.paginator.firstPage();  
    }  
  }  

  loadAllAlbums() {  
    this.service.getAllAlbum().subscribe(data => {  
      this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(data);  
      this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;  
      this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;  
    });  
  }  

  onFormSubmit() {  
    this.dataSaved = false;  
    const album = this.albumForm.value;  
    this.CreateAlbum(album);  
    this.albumForm.reset();  
    this.toastr.success("Created successfully!");
  }  

  loadAlbumToEdit(albumId: string) {  
    this.service.getAlbumById(albumId).subscribe(album => {  
      this.massage = null;  
      this.dataSaved = false;  
      this.albumIdUpdate = album.Id;  
      this.albumForm.controls['Title'].setValue(album.Title);  
      this.albumForm.controls['Year'].setValue(album.Year);  
      this.albumForm.controls['Artist'].setValue(album.ArtistId);  
      this.albumForm.controls['Label'].setValue(album.LabelId);
    });
  }  

  CreateAlbum(album: Album) {  
    console.log(album.Title);  
    if (this.albumIdUpdate == null) {  
      album.ArtistId = this.ArtistId;  
      album.LabelId = this.LabelId;  
   
      this.service.createAlbum(album).subscribe(  
        () => {  
          this.dataSaved = true;  
          this.SavedSuccessful(1);  
          this.loadAllAlbums();  
          this.albumIdUpdate = null;  
          this.albumForm.reset();  
        }  
      );  
    } else {  
      album.Id = this.albumIdUpdate;  
      album.ArtistId = this.ArtistId;  
      album.LabelId = this.LabelId;   
      this.service.updateAlbum(album).subscribe(() => {  
        this.dataSaved = true;  
        this.SavedSuccessful(0);  
        this.loadAllAlbums();  
        this.albumIdUpdate = null;  
        this.albumForm.reset();  
      });  
    }  
  }  

  deleteAlbum(albumId: string) {  
    if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this ?")) {  
      this.service.deleteAlbum(albumId).subscribe(() => {  
        this.dataSaved = true;  
        this.SavedSuccessful(2);  
        this.loadAllAlbums();  
        this.albumIdUpdate = null;  
        this.albumForm.reset();  
   
      });  
    }  
   
  }  

  FillArtistDDL() {  
    this.allArtist = this.service.getAllArtist(); 
  }  
   
  FillLabelDDL() {  
    this.allLabel = this.service.getAllLabel(); 
  }  
   
  GetSelectedArtist(Artist) {  
    this.ArtistId = Artist.value;  
  }  
   
  GetSelectedLabel(Label){
      this.LabelId=Label.value;
  }

  resetForm() {  
    this.albumForm.reset();  
    this.massage = null;  
    this.dataSaved = false;  
    this.loadAllAlbums();  
  }  
   
  SavedSuccessful(isUpdate) {  
    if (isUpdate == 0) {  
      this._snackBar.open('Record Updated Successfully!', 'Close', {  
        duration: 2000,  
        horizontalPosition: this.horizontalPosition,  
        verticalPosition: this.verticalPosition,  
      });  
    }  
    else if (isUpdate == 1) {  
      this._snackBar.open('Record Saved Successfully!', 'Close', {  
        duration: 2000,  
        horizontalPosition: this.horizontalPosition,  
        verticalPosition: this.verticalPosition,  
      });  
    }  
    else if (isUpdate == 2) {  
      this._snackBar.open('Record Deleted Successfully!', 'Close', {  
        duration: 2000,  
        horizontalPosition: this.horizontalPosition,  
        verticalPosition: this.verticalPosition,  
      });  
    }  
  }  
}
```

I did everything with imports , something wrong with kind of injection but where? I`m truly exhausted. Because it does not go to this component URL and trim it and throws an error as mentioned above.

Comment: You should try to remove all your component dependencies (and comment the code that depended on them) and start adding them back one by one. This is how you find the one that breaks your app. Then you do the same (remove all and add them back one by one) for the dependencies of that.

Comment: It did not help me. So an error occurs on account of HttpClientModule or idk. Because I removed all of them and nothing. It is odd because it does not write where it happened...